# The existence of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem with linear algebra: Given $\theta \in V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k-\{0\}$ such that $H\theta=0$ for some full rank $d \times k$ matrix, with $d\leq k$. If $r \in \mathbb{R}^d$, can we find a full rank $d \times k$ matrix $A$ such that $A\theta=r$?
Thanks

Comment: Definition of $A$ is not clear and if $\theta = 0$ we cant have $A\theta = r$ no?

Comment: $A$ is the matrix that I would like to find. And $\theta$ must not be zero

Answer (score 1):

if $r \ne 0$, Take a basis of $\mathbb{R} ^ k$ containing $\theta$ and Take a basis of $\mathbb{R} ^ d$ containing $r$. Define $A(\theta)=r$ and for remaining basis vectors of $\mathbb{R} ^k$ you can defining $A$ suitably so that $A$ is of full rank.

If $r=0$, Take a basis of $\mathbb{R} ^ k$ containing $\theta$ and define $A(\theta)=r$ and for remaining basis vectors of $\mathbb{R} ^k$ you can defining $A$ suitably so that $A$ is of full rank. this is possible as $d \le k$

We dont need that condition $H(\theta) = 0$